# How to make ana alias for a type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, alias

I want to make an alias type based on a condition. It' s like this:

```
if(true == something)
    using MyAlias = MyType1;
else
    using MyAlias = MyType2;

MyAlias boom = ...
```

Is it possible in C#?

Comment: Why not use interface instead?

Comment: This is not possible, but what are you trying to do? There could be an alternative way.

Comment: C# does not support macros (like C++)

Comment: @General-Doomer are you sure C++ allows one to do this on `if` (as opposed to `#if`)?

Comment: It is possible to use preprocessor directives (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) to change the behavior depending on the project options, not using the if instruction

Comment: I think C++ templates can this, but it is very very doog that C# does not supports code like code above :)

Comment: It is really not clear what you're trying to achieve. Your question ask how to make something [type alias] that don't exist in specific language. There is a possibility that what you trying to say is achievable  in a different way in C#